# Retrieving data from multiple resultsets into a single java list

Tags: java, spring, list

I have following three resultsets and a list. How can i iterate the three resultsets without using three while(rs1.next()) and return the data to the list.

```
public Optional<List<StudentDetails>> getStudDetails(String id)
    {
        List<StudentDetails> stud= new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();
        ResultSet rs1 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(4);
        ResultSet rs2 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(5);
        ResultSet rs3 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(6);

    }
```

Comment: You can't. There's no way you can get info from a result set without iterating on it.

Comment: you don't need to use loop if there is only one object in the resultset. Use simple if statement.

Comment: @NishadKAhamed My three resultsets returns three tables. So do i need to use three while loops to get the data?

Comment: definitely not. use if statements to check if there is data available on the result set. I will post an answer, please refer it.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to avoid writing the same code for all `ResultSet`s (3 loops) you could create a method that loops through a `ResultSet`, generates `StudentDetails` objects for each row and adds those to a list.

Here is an example:

```
public Optional<List<StudentDetails>> getStudDetails(String id){
    List<StudentDetails> stud= new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();
    ResultSet rs1 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(4);
    ResultSet rs2 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(5);
    ResultSet rs3 = (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(6);
    addStudentDetails(stud, rs1);
    addStudentDetails(stud, rs2);
    addStudentDetails(stud, rs3);
}

private static void addStudentDetails(List<StudentDetails> list, ResultSet rs){
    while(rs.next()){
        list.add(new StudentDetails(rs.get.....));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer (+1), but two improvements: 1) Make `getStudentDetails` `private` and `static`, 2) Pass `List<StudentDetails> stud` to the `getStudentDetails` method, so it can add objects directly to the list, rather than having to create temporary list. Code then becomes `addStudentDetails(stud, (ResultSet) storedProcedureCall.getObject(4));`

Comment: You can even get rid of the `rs1`, `rs2`, and `rs3` local variables, and just do the `getObject()` call directly in the call to `addStudentDetails()`, as illustrated at the end of my previous comment.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I guess so, but I'm sure the OP got the idea I was trying to illustrate and will modify this example to better fit his needs and preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If the resultset contains only a single object, then you dont need to go for loops. Instead use simple if statements to check if the data is available.

Something like:

```
if(resultSet.hasNext()){
   Object obj= objresultSet.next();
}
```

do this for all of your ResultSet Objects